# Linux search a specific text in specific log files based on date

Tags: linux, shell

I would like a search for a specific text called TEXT_ID but it is taking too much time..

I would like instead to filter the search to only files with a specific date..
My log files have this patters *log.2020-02-25T10.28.01.956-f4b54c

I have tried this but no result:

> find  /opt/apps/shared/log/ -type f -ls | grep '2020-02-24' | grep -r
>   "TEXT_ID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command:

```
find /opt/apps/shared/log/ -type f -ls | grep '2020-02-24' | grep -r "TEXT_ID"
```

search for specific text in list which contain filenames. You do not search in the content of the files.

You can try something like

```
find /opt/apps/shared/log/ -type f -name "*2020-02-24* "-exec grep "TEXT_ID" {} \;
```